# How to extract vocals from a music file when you have the original instrumental?

Tags: audacity

I don't know how to perfectly use the instrumental for extracting the vocals in audacity when they are not quite identical.

Comment: What about them is 'not identical'?

Comment: @Tetsujin They are not linked, some is 1 second less than the other.

Comment: If they are nothing like each other, then they are useless to each other. The trick you're after requires phase-coherence. Without that, you need Izotope RX7, a mere 400 bucks, & it's still not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Is there any way to link them automatically without zooming in audacity so they meet phase-coherence? @Tetsujin

Comment: No. Phase-coherence is the only way to do this. If they are not identical you cannot use phase-reversal to do this. They need to match to sample-level. If they don't *quite* then you could do it in chunks, "cut & shut", but if they're nowhere near you don't have a hope.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the noise reduction option. Use the instrumental audio for the 'noise profile' and apply that profile to the one with the vocals. Not sure if that will work but that appears to be the only option at this point.